# Highcharts area graph stacking one series on to another

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, area, stacked

This is a bit of a complex request and there is very probably not an easy way to complete this. I am trying to create a stacked area between two series.

I have two metrics, Y1 and Y2, that need to be graphed. The graph needs to show Y1 as an area for series 1, and the difference between Y1 and Y2 as an area for series 2 (with Y2 always being positive -- therefore, series 2 will always be more positive than series 1). That means the area for series 2 should not be from its line to the axis, but to series 1.

My best attempt has been this graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdmwl.png. The goal I'm trying to achieve is to have the the black series 2 (underneath the blue series 1) to shade in the inverse of what is overlapped by the blue. If the blue series 1 is positive, the black series 2 would be even more positive and the area would be between its line and the blue series 1 line.

The data for 5/2015 here are -600,000 for Series 1 and +500,000 for Series 2, so I would want the 500,000 difference between the two values to be colored by the black, rather than the -100,000.

Comment: Honestly, could you create jsfiddle with actual demo to test it? Also, have you tried to use `arearange` series instead? See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.arearange).